# Idiom for doing "space age" stuff instead of what is necessary

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language, idiom-requests

What is a good way to call someone out who prefers doing the new, cool, and shiny thing over doing what is really necessary?

Comment: So you want *mountains out of molehills* for using GPS when there is plenty of signage?  Overcomplicating a task with technology...

Answer (score 2):

Wait just a moment while I put down this new IPhone IX and go back to my trusty ol' TRS-80 ... there, that's better ... OK, you could try this brand new word I've been introduced to (it's what all my friends call me), **kainomaniac**

> [**kainomania**](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-kainomania) *noun*: 1. a morbid interest in novelty or new trends. 2. A strong tendency to possess new things. (Encyclo.Co.UK)

Answer (score 1):

A [hipster](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hipster):

> - One who is exceptionally aware of or interested in the latest trends and tastes. (AHD)
> - A person who follows the latest trends and fashions, especially those regarded as being outside the cultural mainstream. (ODO)